# I installed react-router-dom as dependency with npm install, but it installed in another separated package.json, how to install it on the same

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm new in React and VS Code in general so, I really need an explanation about dependencies and all that stuff.

I just installed react-router-dom from the terminal but it created a separated package.json

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dOSLhPzSGI
I was seeing this video
Timestamp: 22:11
I just want to have the react-router-dom installed in the same package as the other dependencies.
HOW DO I DO THAT?

Comment: You have to call it out of the correct directory. Maybe you created a project and after that called npm install without changing into the project directory first?

Comment: you'll need to describe in much more detail what you are actually observing and what steps are necessary to reproduce the issue. Please also add version info for all your things.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command npm install react-router-dom again in this root directory

Comment: how do I do that? Do I need to open the terminal and type npm install react-router-dom?

Comment: First run `cd path/to/your/projectfolder` (obviously the path has to be replaced with the correct path). Then run `npm install react-router-dom`.